# Checking out products for "free"

Tags: united-kingdom, website

I added products to my digital "shopping cart" worth $700, I was going to pay for it and I'd filled in my adres and completed the form, however the site immediately directed me to the final phase of payment without actually paying for it, I got an email of verification.

Do they actually have to ship their products to me and under what conditions?

Comment: @Nij Thanks for the reference but can you throw this into an answer?

Comment: I believe you misunderstand. I am saying the question has already been answered, therefore, this version of it should be closed, not answered again.

Comment: I understood. so i made an agreement and the seller confirmed it by a verification email, thus he is forced to send his items. Is this the right convertion?

Comment: No. You have not formed a contract, or at least, you have not provided the consideration expected of you. If the seller sent the items and you did not pay despite requesting them, you would be liable for the payment or for returning them plus compensating any actual loss.

Comment: But if it wasn't my intention to become this, and the seller didn't provide the right steps to checkout but i assume this is another question..

Comment: Well, it **was** your intention to purchase the items for those prices. A technical issue of the seller does not excuse the legal issue for you.